# Explain string representation of Context

Tags: android

Out of curiosity, I displayed the string representation of context using following piece of code :

```
this.toString() + "\n" + getApplicationContext().toString() + "\n" + getBaseContext().toString()
```

It gave me:

`com.example.makz.bud.MainActivity@b0fe7ef0
 android.app.Application@b0fe62a0
 android.app.ContextImpl@b0fe9c88`
`

- What does the hex values represent?
- Can I get any useful information from those values ?

Answer (score 1):

From `com.example.makz.bud.MainActivity@b0fe7ef0` you can get that concrete implementation of Context is of type`com.example.makz.bud.MainActivity` and it is allocated in `b0fe7ef0` memory location (hex representation of default hashCode).

This is the default representation of `toString()` method in Java.

Comment: No. b0fe7ef0 - is not memory location. It's hex representation of hashCode(). You can find implemetation here:http://developer.android.com/reference/java/lang/Object.html

Comment: Default implementation of `hashCode` is memory location. Isn't it? http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/Object.html#hashCode()

Comment: Sorry, you are right. There is only recommendation on that page. Therefore, I don't suggest to use hashCode to get information about memory allocation, because convenience about hashCode() doesn't guarantee this.

Comment: Sure, I don't recommend it, too.

Answer (score 0):

You can find in source, that Context doesn't override toString() method.
So it's default representation of Java Object.toString() method (according to documentation):

```
getClass().getName() + '@' + Integer.toHexString(hashCode())
```

So, I think you can't get usefull information from this